# How to access angularjs constant from regular Javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way we can access AngularJS constant in normal Javascript function in a different file?

I have example below:

```
angular.module('app').constant('env', {
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/'
});
```

How do I access env constant in Javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you had an element the app was initialised on:

```
<div id="app" ng-app="yourApp"></div>
```

Get an injector using the angular function:

```
var inj = angular.element(document.getElementById('app')).injector();
var constant = inj.get('myConstant'); // in your case, env
```

Comment: How am I able to access angular object in regular Gulp task js file?

Comment: You could have mentioned gulp in your question

Comment: No worries maybe I should have been more descriptive. How do I do this in Gulp?